# WQO - why transitivity?

Tags: combinatorics, relations, order-theory

This [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-quasi-ordering) says that $\sf WQO$s are a strenghtening of the definition of well-founded relations for the purpose of having the property be preserved by operations. However, the few operations and proofs (minimal bad sequence arguments) that I know about don't seem to need the extra assumption of transitivity. The only exception is the product of relations/posets but it can be done with infinite Ramsey's theorem. Is transitivity used in other parts of $\sf WQO/BQO$ theory?

Comment: Please state what the acronyms stand for.

Comment: @amWhy WQO stands for well-quasi-ordering, BQO for better-quasi-ordering

Comment: What about the fact that a well-quasi-ordering is, to start with, a quasi-ordering? Then, of course, you could ask why not defining a different concept altogether, but that is something else. Perhaps wqos are used in different contexts than the ones you know?

Comment: @amrsa it would probably need a different name without transitivity, but ultimately that's just one simple assumption in the definition. If wqos are used in a context where transitivity is needed then that's what I'm asking about.

Comment: How do you define a *quasi-order*?

Comment: @AsafKaragila a quasiorder is a reflexive and transitive binary relation

Answer (score 1):

This likely isn't the greatest theorem of WQO theory but for an example, a qoset is WQO iff it has no infinite decreasing chains nor infinite antichains. This fails for WQO-minus-transitivity, consider the relation $\preceq$ on $\mathbb{N}$ such that $a \preceq b \iff a=b \lor a=b+1 \lor (a<b \land a\equiv b \mod 2)$. There is an infinite decreasing chain $0\succ1\succ2\ldots$ but in an infinite sequence we will eventually have two numbers of same parity in increasing order.